# Program runs twice - Proper Use of Main

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point

Trying to figure out why my squads function runs twice. Most of the functions near the bottom take the data from the previous function as input and the last function finds the max in list of lists.
I want to setup my main properly here so that 1) in this program everything runs properly and 2) that when called from another program that it will just run squads on its own and return the value from squads to that program

It looks like squads runs twice as my outer while loop prints "iter one done" - twice. Having said that how should I setup my main?

How this works -

The first function squads returns a list of lists
Second function - goals_convert_dash - takes the output from first func (squads)- takes two elements (from each list) in the lists of lists and if there is a dash (-) converts that to zero.
.Third func - goals_convert_toint takes the output from goals_convert_dash and converts the second column to a zero.
Fourth - get_max then gets the max from the 2nd column from and outputs that along with the data from the first column zero

If it runs correctly I think the output should be -

iter one done
Premier league top goal scorer is: 
['John Smith', 11]

My current output is currently -

```
iter one done
Premier league top goal scorer is: 
['John Smith', 11]
iter one done
```

Program -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
from operator import itemgetter
from scrape1_squad_urls import table

base_url = 'https://someurl.com'


# Squad Data

team_table = table()

#team_names = team_urls()
def squads():


    strip_team_name = [i.replace('https://www.someurl.com', '') for i in team_table]
    full_strip = [i.replace('-squad', '') for i in strip_team_name]

    iter = 0
    while iter < 1:
        tdstrip = []
        x = []
        tdstripclean = []
        for i in team_table:


                squad_r = requests.get(i)

        #        print(squad_r.status_code)

                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(squad_r.text, 'html.parser')

        #       div = soup.find('div', {'class': '-bp30-box col span1/1'})
                premier_squad_table = premier_squad_soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'table -small no-wrap football-squad-table '})
                headings = []
                playerurls = []
                full_links = []


                strip_team_name = [i.replace('https://someurl.com/', '') for i in team_table]
                full_strip = [i.replace('-squad', '') for i in strip_team_name]
                find_team_name = soup.find('span',{'class': 'swap-text__target'})
                for table in premier_squad_table:

                    table_head = table.find('thead')
                    head_rows = table_head.find_all('tr')

                    for item in head_rows:
                        headers = item.find_all('th')

                    table_body = table.find('tbody')
                    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
                    for row in rows:
                        td = row.find_all('td')
                        x = [x.text.strip() for x in td]
                        position_teamname = (headers[0].text,find_team_name.text)
                        x[2]
                        x.extend(position_teamname)
                        tdstrip.append(x)
        iter = iter + 1
        print("iter one done")
    return(tdstrip)

#   return(newList)
#squads()

def goals_convert_dash():

    tdstrip = squads()  

    indexes = [0,2]
    newList = [[each_list[i] for i in indexes ] for each_list in tdstrip ]
    for eachlist in newList:
        if eachlist[1] == '-':
            eachlist[1] = 0
    return(newList) 
#goals_convert_dash()



#print(newList)

def goals_convert_toint():
    converted = goals_convert_dash()

    for eachlist in converted:
        eachlist[1] = int(eachlist[1])
    return(converted)        

#goals_convert_toint()


def get_max(lst, i, key_func=None):

    if not key_func: key_func = lambda x: x[i]
    res = max(lst, key=key_func)
    return [res[0], res[i]]

data = goals_convert_toint()

print("Premier league top goal scorer is: ")

print(get_max(data,1, lambda x: int(x[1])))

if __name__ == '__main__':
     squads()
#    goals_convert_dash()
#    goals_convert_toint()
#    get_max()
```

Comment: `tdstrip = squads() ` - this calls `squads`. It's within `goals_convert_dash`, which is called from `goals_convert_toint` - which is called directly from the main script (`data = goals_convert_toint()`)

Comment: How do I fix it

Comment: That depends on what you want the overall program to do,and what each function does. It's not totally clear without any explanation. (But looking without knowing any of these things, it doesn't appear that the second call to `squads`, in the main program, actually does anything observable.)

Comment: Ive updated the description, does that help

Comment: In `main()` Call the function which will be responsible for executing all other function. You can relook over the architecture of the program.

Comment: I understand that it needs to be re-organised, and that's the part I am trying to figure out